# Generate Cartesian product of each word from file1 x file2

Tags: python, cartesian-product

I have searched lots of sites and forums and I can't make it work. I used read(), readline() combining all kind of solutions. I tried while and for loop and still can't figure it out.
Here is the task. I have 2 files with `txt` extension. So file1 is `list1.txt` and file 2 is `list2.txt`

list1.txt have

```
dog
flower
person
```

list2.txt have

```
123
456
```

What I want is next. new document list3.txt with:

```
dog123
dog456
flower123
flower456
person123
person456
```

But i can't use itertool because i can not merge 2 files. Thats forbiden.
Any1 can help in finding solution or give some advice.

Comment: Does "i can't use itertool because i can not merge 2 files. Thats forbiden." mean you can't use `itertools` at all? Or just that you can't manually make one file and use `itertools`?

Comment: I was just sugesting that answer can't be: "copy all to one list.txt and use combination, permutation or something similar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
with open('list1.txt', 'r') as l1, open('list2.txt', 'r') as l2, open('list3.txt', 'w') as l3:
    for left_part in l1:
        for right_part in l2:
            l3.write('%s%s\n' % (left_part.replace("\n",""), right_part.replace("\n","")))
        l2.seek(0)
```

Comment: Why not just use `with` so you don't have to close the file? https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Comment: please note, I've added closing list1.txt and list2.txt

Comment: well this code isn't same as first one. I mean this doesnt work.. it gives me only first word from list1 with wirst word from list2. I hade to stop script because it writes n/a times

Comment: Are you sure? I've tested it. Please note that there is l2.seek(0)

Comment: Probably you've put l2.seek(0) inside the second loop?

Comment: now it works... I placed l2.seek(o) same as l3.write. IT was under second loop and not first one. Thanks.. Its more elegante :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Docs on Input and Output:](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

```
with open('list1.txt', 'r') as l1, open('list2.txt', 'r') as l2, open('list3.txt', 'w') as l3:
    for i, l in enumerate(l1):
        x = l1.readline()
        for j, k in enumerate(l2):
            l3.write('%s%s' % (x, l2.readline()))
```

Comment: You can combine those first three lines into one.